# Production Push Notification .p12 Production Certificate not working for Enterprise Distribution App (outside of app store)

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I've tried to send push notification using "Development SSL Certificate" or the sandbox .p12 cert the iphone is able to receive notification sent from MobileFirst Operations Console.

However, when I replace the sandbox .p12 cert with the production one, I couldn't receive push notification. I even deleted the device app, remove the device from the registered list and re-register the device. But I'm still getting the same result.

Are there any additional settings needed?

MFP server version is "Product version: 8.0.0.00-20170220-1900"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Update:***

From this [MobileFirst tutorial Link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#setting-up-notifications)
"The APNS production certificate can only be tested once the application that utilizes it has been successfully submitted to the Apple App Store."

What about in house distribution app/"save for Enterprise Deployment" outside of the app store?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the push notification capability is enabled from the capabilities tab of the project target if you are deploying your application from xcode 8.0 or later.
[image]

This should be on if you deploy your application from xcode 8 or later.

Comment: this setting is already in place. updated my question with the screenshot for this setting

Answer (score 0):

For push notifications to be sent, the following servers must be accessible from a MobileFirst Server instance:

**Sandbox servers:**

> - gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
> - feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196

**Production servers:**

> - gateway.push.apple.com:2195
> - Feedback.push.apple.com:2196
> - 1-courier.push.apple.com 5223

- During the development phase, use the apns-certificate-sandbox.p12 sandbox certificate file.
- During the production phase, use the apns-certificate-production.p12 production certificate file.

Reference : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#apple-push-notifications-service

Comment: I'm using the local mfp server... I doubt it's because of the port.

Comment: check that server is working from your system ? ping that server url from command line and check..

Comment: How to perform the check. For local server, sandbox cert is working and production cert is not.

Comment: ping gateway.push.apple.com

Comment: I'm able to ping the sandbox server "ping gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195" and receive response... However, I couldn't "ping gateway.push.apple.com"... Do I need to include the port number? How to open it to receive push from my macbook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141895/discussion-between-gaurab-kumar-and-user1872384).

Comment: Is there a need to setup .pem in local mfp server or AWS mfp server?

Comment: no .. here you have to use only .p12 certificate format.

Comment: Yes exactly .p12 is sufficient. So what are the additional settings needed to get the production cert to work then? In the IBM tutorial link it's stated that "The APNS production certificate can only be tested once the application that utilizes it has been successfully submitted to the Apple App Store." However, I'm distributing it as enterprise app outside of the app store. Does it mean that it will not work?

Comment: I get you... So means it's not the type of cert that is causing the issue. I have no idea how to enable the connection to gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141940/discussion-between-gaurab-kumar-and-user1872384).